# Custom validation error using Sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Is possible to customize the error from the

> Sequelize.ValidationError

Model:

```
  var PaymentType = sequelize.define('payment_type' , {
      id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      field: 'id'
    },
    code: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate:{
        notEmpty: true
      },
      field: 'code'
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate:{
        notEmpty: true
      },
      field: 'name'
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: false,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'payment_types'
  });
```

My controller:

```
  update(req, res) {
      paymentType
        .update(req.body, {
          where: {
            id: req.params.id
          }
        })
        .then( updatedRecords => {
          res.status(200).json(updatedRecords);
        })
        .catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, error => {
          res.status(400).json(error);
        })
        .catch( error => {
          res.status(500).json(error);
        });

  },
```

The errors I get, are this way:

```
{
  "name": "SequelizeValidationError",
  "message": "Validation error: Validation notEmpty failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Validation notEmpty failed",
      "type": "Validation error",
      "path": "name",
      "value": {},
      "__raw": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to pass the errors like this(only path and message):

```
{
"name":"The field cannot be empty",
"other_field":"custom error message"
}
```

I don't know if I can specify a custom message in the model or I have to create a function to build the errors messages.

If I have to build a function, how can I extract the path and customize the message?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You cant change default sequelize.validation error message, so you can simply catch that message from validation and put if condtions and you can write custom message inside catch and return that as response.

Answer (score 6):

You can catch Sequelize's **ValidationError** and loop through its **ValidationErrorItem**'s and write a custom message depending on the error type (determined by **ValidationErrorItem.validatorKey**). Here is a code snippet to get started.

```
try {
 // sequelize custom logic here
} catch(e) {
    const messages = {};
    if (e instanceof ValidationError) {
        e.errors.forEach((error) => {
            let message;
            switch (error.validatorKey) {
                case 'isEmail':
                    message = 'Please enter a valid email';
                    break;
                case 'isDate':
                    message = 'Please enter a valid date';
                    break;
                case 'len':
                    if (error.validatorArgs[0] === error.validatorArgs[1]) {
                        message = 'Use ' + error.validatorArgs[0] + ' characters';
                    } else {
                        message = 'Use between ' + error.validatorArgs[0] + ' and ' + error.validatorArgs[1] + ' characters';
                    }
                    break;
                case 'min':
                    message = 'Use a number greater or equal to ' + error.validatorArgs[0];
                    break;
                case 'max':
                    message = 'Use a number less or equal to ' + error.validatorArgs[0];
                    break;
                case 'isInt':
                    message = 'Please use an integer number';
                    break;
                case 'is_null':
                    message = 'Please complete this field';
                    break;
                case 'not_unique':
                    message = error.value + ' is taken. Please choose another one';
                    error.path = error.path.replace("_UNIQUE", "");
            }
            messages[error.path] = message;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: ValidationError is not defined

Comment: if (e instanceof Sequelize.ValidationError) { #solved

Answer (score 5):

You can specify a custom message for sequelize Validation, Your code will look something like this

```
`var PaymentType = sequelize.define('payment_type' , {
  id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true,
  field: 'id'
},
code: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  validate:{
    notEmpty: {
      args: true,
      msg: “code cannot be empty"
    }
  },
  field: 'code'
},
name: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  validate:{
    notEmpty: {
      args: true,
      msg: “code cannot be empty"
    }
  },
  field: 'name'
}
```

I specified the validation rule as an object, in the above case, `notEmpty` should be true so I refactored it to an object setting the `args` property to `true` i.e `notEmpty` should be `true`, and the second property is `msg` which contains our custom message

`notEmpty: {
    args: true,
    msg: “code cannot be empty"
 }`

Comment: `args: true` should not be used anymore I think unless the validator actually needs an argument, otherwise it leads to weird errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522387/unhandled-rejection-sequelizevalidationerror-validation-error-cannot-create-pr/70263032#70263032

Answer (score 3):

Do you try to change Model like this:

```
 var PaymentType = sequelize.define('payment_type' , {
      id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      field: 'id'
    },
    code: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate:{
        notEmpty: {
          msg: "The field cannot be empty"
        }
      },
      field: 'code'
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate:{
        notEmpty: {
          msg: "The field cannot be empty"
        }
      },
      field: 'name'
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: false,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'payment_types'
  });
```

[Reference this post](https://hiddentao.com/archives/2011/11/12/adding-model-validation-to-the-sequelize-orm-library-for-node-js/)

Comment: You can check how to add more validations here https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html