# Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: Validation error: Cannot create property 'allow_display_name' on boolean 'true'

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have installed sequelize ORM for nodejs project and getting below error

*Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: Validation error: Cannot create property 'allow_display_name' on boolean 'true'*

Answer (score 3):

In my models I have put one validation for valid email where I have value like below

```
validate: {
        isEmail: {
          args: true,
          message: 'Please enter a valid Email address'
        }
      }
```

I just changed the `arg: true` to `arg: false` and its worked.

Answer (score 0):

Tested as of Sequelize 6.5.1, you should just remove `args` from the validation. Also it should now be `msg` and not `message`. This gives:

```
validate: {
  isEmail: {
    msg: 'Please enter a valid Email address'
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you didn't want a custom message, you can just use:

```
validate: {
  isEmail: true
}
```

`args:` is now only needed when the validator needs extra arguments, which is not the case for `email`, e.g.:

```
isIn: {
  args: [['en', 'zh']],
  msg: "Must be English or Chinese"
}
```

would ensure that the value is in the Array `['en', 'zh']`, so we needed this extra argument to specify the validator. In those cases, if you don't want a custom error message, you can just pass the argument directly as in:

```
isIn: [['en', 'zh']],
```

Documented at: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210305000123/https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html) and also mentioned on this ticket: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3770.

Note that most validators come from this third party library: Agithub.com/validatorjs/validator.js though that is not very clear in the docs. Their README shows that `allow_display_name` which is related to where it comes from.

BTW: the reason we have to do `[['en', 'zh']]` rather than just `['en', 'zh']` is that for array arguments, we have to differentiate between:

- argument 1: `'en'`, argument 2: `zh` (not what we want)
- argument 1: `['en', 'zh']`

For non-Arrays, the typechecks just make an array with:

- argument 1: `[nonArray]`

and splat that into validatejs. [Coded here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/5d18f39f9297269215600a6f3af0fd2736330186/lib/instance-validator.js#L323).